# How send this.state at other component and do render in the parent

Tags: reactjs

I am consuming an api from a component to render the results using another component called datagrid, if I consume the api from the component called datagrid everything works fine, but the idea is to consume the api only once, the problem is not the api, The problem is that the data grid component does not receive the new value of this.state.

```
class Color extends Component {

    state = {
        fields: {
            colorCodigo: null,
            colorNombre: '',
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        //CONSUMO API.
        const params = this.props.match.params;

        if (!params.id) {
            return;
        }

        getDocument({
            documentId: params.id,
            fieldName: 'colorCodigo',
            moduleName: params.module
        }).then(document => {
            if (!document) {
                return;
            }
            this.setState({ fields: document });
        });

    }


    render() {


        return (


            <Paper elevation={5} className={this.props.classes.mainPaper}>
                <Datagrid datos={this.state.fields} />
            </Paper >


        );


    }


}


export default withStyles(styles)(Color);




class Datagrid extends Component {


    componentDidMount = () => {


        console.log("aqui entra en el render de Color y no muestra nada y 
      esta bien pero en el re - render de color cuando se actualiza el 
      estado no llega aqui para trabajar con la data que llega de la 
       api");



    console.log(this.props.datos);


    }

    render() {


        const { classes } = this.props;


        return (


            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <Table className={classes.table}>
                    ......
        </Table>
            </Paper>


        );
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(Datagrid);
```

Comment: Are you only logging the props when the Datagrid component mounts? If so the ```datos``` prop would not be available yet as it has to wait to be returned from the API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention, look:

The code is applied in the following sequence without data:

1. (http: // localhost: 3000 / color /)

2. Color: componentWillMount
3.DataGrid: componentWillMount
4.DataGrid: componentDidMount
5. Color: componentDidMount

6. Color: componentWillReceiveProps
7.Color: shouldComponentUpdate
8.Color: componentWillUpdate
9.Datagrid: componentWillReceiveProps

10.Datagrid: shouldComponentUpdate
11.Datagrid: componentWillUpdate
12.Datagrid: componentDidUpdate
13. Color: componentDidUpdate

Comment: 14.Color: shouldComponentUpdate
15. Color: componentWillUpdate
16.Datagrid: componentWillReceiveProps
17.Datagrid: shouldComponentUpdate

18.Datagrid: componentWillUpdate
19.Datagrid: componentDidUpdate
20.Color: componentDidUpdate

accessing the api
1. (http: // localhost: 3000 / color / 6 / edit)

The code executes the previous sequence and shows the form, then makes this sequence:

Color: 1.shouldComponentUpdate
2.Color: componentWillUpdate
3.Datagrid: componentWillReceiveProps
4.Datagrid: shouldComponentUpdate
5.Datagrid: componentWillUpdate

Comment: 6.Datagrid: componentDidUpdate
7. Color: componentDidUpdate

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that consuming an API is asynchronous, so even though the ```componentDidMount()``` for the DataGrid will run, the value of ```datos``` will be undefined if the response hasn't come back yet.  What are you rendering in the ```...``` section of the DataGrid component?  If whatever it is depends on ```datos``` and is still not updating then it's something else, but if you're relying solely on the ```console.log()``` in ```componentDidMount()```, I can see why you may be getting an undefined result.